# Instantiating Groovy class in Java

Tags: groovy

Hi I have a Groovy classs which looks like this :

```
class CustomVanityDetails {

private String serial;
private String abbv;
private String desc;

public String getSerial() {
    return serial;
}
public void setSerial(String serial) {
    this.serial = serial;
}
public String getAbbv() {
    return abbv;
}
public void setAbbv(String abbv) {
    this.abbv = abbv;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
```

Now i am creating object and setting the properties in my **JAVA** class like this :

```
    CustomVanityDetails customVanity = new CustomVanityDetails();
    customVanity.setSerial("213");
    customVanity.setAbbv("test");
    customVanity.setDesc("testing");

    ArrayList<CustomVanityDetails > arrayList = new ArrayList<CustomVanityDetails >();
    arrayList.add(customVanity);
    return arrayList
```

Now the problem i am facing is that when i access this **arraylist** in my Groovy code,the properties are **null**.

Comment: What do you mean, "the properties are null"? Can you provide a unit test or something showing the problem? What you have shown here should work fine.

Comment: @cjstehno  : By saying properties are null i mean to say that if i try `arrayList.get(1).getSerial()`,it returns null

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean `arrayList.get(0).getSerial()` right - since you only have one element in your example.

Comment: yep, please provide us the piece of code which works incorrectly

Comment: @cjstehno yeah i mean `arrayList.get(0).getSerial()` is returning  null

Comment: i found the problem...Actually my groovy class contained **public** keyword : `public class CustomVanityDetails ` . After i removed public it started working fine.Thank you guys for giving me your time.

Comment: I believe it was something else, not just `public` keyword. I've copy-pasted your code to GroovyConsole, added `public` but it still working fine